# How can I find large Kafka messages?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

## The problem

My app, reading message from several topics by mask, crashes with error:

```
Confluent.Kafka.ConsumeException: Broker: Message size too large
```

## What I've tried

The first problem is that I followed the guidelines for handling large messages: `fetch.max.bytes`, `message.max.bytes` and `receive.message.max.bytes` configurations is set to limits:

```cs
ConsumerSettings = new KafkaConsumerSettings(...)
    .With(x => x.ConsumerConfig.FetchMaxBytes   = 2_000_000_000)
    .With(x => x.ConsumerConfig.MessageMaxBytes = 1_000_000_000)
    .With(x => x.ConsumerConfig.ReceiveMessageMaxBytes = 2_000_000_000 + 512);
// `fetch.max.bytes` must be >= `message.max.bytes`
// `message.max.bytes` must be in range 1000..1000000000
// `receive.message.max.bytes` must be >= `fetch.max.bytes` + 512
```

But the application still cannot process the message. So I decided to skip this message

The second problem is that I can't find the message that is causing the error. I have identified topics that have stopped processing (`CURRENT-OFFSET` not changed and `LAG` not equal 0). I checked the `CURRENT-OFFSET` messages - they are all small in size:

```
$ kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server ***:9092  --group "Khajiit.GlobalCatalog.KpcCategoryCalculator.V1" --describe

at 2022.02.18:
TOPIC                                                             PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG      
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Rng.V3    0          34254397        34876289        621892   
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Rng.V3    1          34713480        34713480        0        
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Rng.V3    2          34717961        34717961        0        
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Edi.V3    0          22851397        70600273        47748876 
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Edi.V3    1          5062234         69250288        64188054 
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Edi.V3    2          1538710         70360554        68821844 
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Ubr.V3    0          58093545        60426064        2332519  
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Ubr.V3    2          58127630        60451357        2323727   (no progress)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Market.V3 1          445647          192860258       192414611
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Market.V3 2          236             192582179       192581943 (no progress)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Fg.V3     0          21818841        23028014        1209173   (no progress)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Fg.V3     2          23055736        23055736        0        
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.X5.V3     0          49773684        50826978        1053294   (no progress)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.X5.V3     1          49801454        50854337        1052883   (no progress)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Gepir.V3  1          3089137         10822241        7733104   (no progress)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Gepir.V3  2          6479987         10830654        4350667  

at 2022.02.21
TOPIC                                                             PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Rng.V3    0          34254740        34876289        621549    (34254740 - 34254397 = 343      messages processed)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Rng.V3    1          34713480        34713480        0        
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Rng.V3    2          34717961        34717961        0        
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Edi.V3    0          54218443        70676247        16457804  (54218443 - 22851397 = 31367046 messages processed)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Edi.V3    1          16219754        69328536        53108782  (16219754 - 5062234  = 11157520 messages processed)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Edi.V3    2          1616692         70441024        68824332  (1616692  - 1538710  = 77982    messages processed)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Ubr.V3    0          58096101        60426064        2329963   (58096101 - 58093545 = 2556     messages processed)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Ubr.V3    2          58127630        60451357        2323727   (no progress)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Market.V3 1          2005847         193217223       191211376 (2005847  - 445647   = 1560200  messages processed)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Market.V3 2          374             192938130       192937756 (374      - 236      = 138      messages processed)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Fg.V3     0          21818841        23028014        1209173   (no progress)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Fg.V3     2          23055736        23055736        0        
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.X5.V3     0          49773684        50826978        1053294   (no progress)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.X5.V3     1          49801454        50854337        1052883   (no progress)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Gepir.V3  1          3089137         10878226        7789089   (no progress)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Gepir.V3  2          6821193         10886253        4065060   (6821193  - 6479987  = 341206   messages processed)

current offset and the next two message sizes:
TOPIC                                                             PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Ubr.V3    2          58127630    (530, 530, 708 bytes)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Fg.V3     0          21818841    (545, 545, 545 bytes)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.X5.V3     0          49773684    (690, 690, 693 bytes)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.X5.V3     1          49801454    (521, 521, 699 bytes)
Khajiit.Content.Aggregation.KpcClassifiedProductChanges.Gepir.V3  1          3089137     (557, 557, 557 bytes)
```

## The question

How can I identify the message that is causing the error?

I'm guessing a solution that will output the largest message sizes for a topic with its partition/offset using command line utilities

Comment: Any advice on how to process the large message without skipping it would also be helpful

Comment: When you skip the event, do you not have its offset /metadata in the consumer?

Comment: No, I have not. While consuming I'm able only to log 'consumer.Assignment.ToLogString()', which looks like list of topics and partitions, without offset/metadata. I cant log `ConsumeResult`, which contain offsets, because app is crashes at  `consumer.Consume()` call

Comment: I thought that this was unnecessary details, so I did not include it in the question itself. You can see the source code and logs here: https://pastebin.com/HihvA2c4

Comment: Oh, right, it's the poll that'll crash... But how are you skipping anything, then? Just catch the exception and rebuild the consumer instance in an exterior loop, then seek the consumer to some further offset? You could lower the max poll size to some really small number, then you'll know it's within that amount from some partition

Comment: "But how are you skipping anything, then?" - Not skipping. try consume, catch exception, fail app, relaunch app and so on in a circle. "You could lower the max poll size to some really small number" - forgot to clarify, already try consume by 1 message

Comment: **UPD**:There is no large messages in my case (check topics with Offset Explorer). The "message size too large" error raises with no relevant to topics/partitions/offsets in my case - consumer crashes with constant period while read "--from-earliest" any of compacted topic at any offset (excluding the end of the topic).

Increase the consume batch size help me to process topics to the end. When processing the end of the topic, the error no longer appears